# How to write addtion program in unix

Tags: unix

I know it is basic question but i am unable to write simple addition program in unix. i am using cygwin to write the shell script my script is this

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "enter the first number"
read a
echo "enter the seconf number"
read b
echo  [$a + $b]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "enter the first number"
read a
echo "enter the seconf number"
read b
echo  $(($a+$b))
```

Comment: [Documentation reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)

Answer (score 0):

To add two numbers, you can do this:

```
let c = $a + $b
echo $c
```

To read, you can do:

```
read -p "Enter the first number" a
read -p "Enter the second number" b
```